# MKMapView night mode like in iOS7 Apple Maps?

Tags: cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mapkit

Is there an easy way to enable night mode on a `MKMapView` like the Apple Maps apps does when the sun is down ?

I didn't find such a thing the MapKit documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it is a private api:

```
//add this above the interface of the class you want to try it on
@interface MKMapView ()
   -(void) _setShowsNightMode:(BOOL)yesOrNo;
@end

//call this in your viewDidLoad or somewhere else appropriate
[self.mapView _setShowsNightMode:YES];
```

We should file a radar for apple to open this up to everyone. It could be a safety issue for people using maps in third party apps while driving. **Your app will be rejected if you try and submit it to the app store using this**.

Comment: Is the same available in swift?  cannot seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

No, you'd have to use a third-party library like [Mapbox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk) or [MBXMapKit](http://mapbox.com/mbxmapkit).

Comment: This might be a better answer because the short answer is no. Using a private API is not acceptable.